# require 'cl or require 'cl-lib

Tags: common-lisp, cl-lib

In order to include Common Lisp compatibility I've seen both

```
(require 'cl)
```

and

```
(require 'cl-lib)
```

Which is correct? As I understand the `cl-lib` is the later of the two, but is it safe to use just it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The first is the old library, the second is the new one.

The old one defines things like `defstruct`, `symbol-macrolet`, `incf`, whereas the second defines instead `cl-defstruct`, `cl-symbol-macrolet`, and `cl-incf`.

The old one is deprecated because it does not obey the general rule that packages should use a "package prefix" for all their definitions to try and avoid conflicts with other packages.  IOW the old one messes up the namespace whereas the new one is careful to only use identifiers which start with `cl-`.

Old versions of Emacs only come with `cl` but you can install the `cl-lib` forward-compatibility package from GNU ELPA which internally uses the old `cl` and just re-exports the same definitions under their new name.

New versions of Emacs come with a real `cl-lib` which does not use `cl` internally and instead they have a `cl` backward-compatibility package which internally uses `cl-lib` and just re-exports the same definitions under their old name.